# pin a UIButton to a MapView

Tags: iphone, uibutton, mkmapview, cgrect

I make a UIButton over an annotationView like this below:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
CGPoint point = [mainMapView convertCoordinate:sac.coordinate toPointToView:self.smallView];
button.frame = CGRectMake(point.x - 30, point.y - 30, 60, 60);
```

It works great, but when I move the map, the buttons do not move with the map. Is there a way to draw the button with a `CGRectMake` that puts the `button.frame` on the map instead of the view?

Answer (score 2):

You really should use The MKMapAnnotation stuff to accomplish that. [this link](http://blog.just2us.com/2010/05/how-to-use-mapkit/) walks you through the basics of setting up the delegates needed. 
Basically all work to keep the button in a location has been done for you--you just have to take advantage of it.
[This class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207) shows how you can set an image for your overlay view and various other things.

Comment: I do use annotations, I have another need that requires buttons in addition to annotations. sac.coordinate is a coordinate property of an annotation.

Comment: So put the button in the annotation view, that's what Josh is saying

Comment: I need an annotation with a custom image that when pressed, creates a button that is larger than the annotation and presents a new Image. I can do all that. All I need is for that button to move along with the map.

Comment: So I guess what you need to do is have you first button cause another annotation to be added to the map. Annotations are anchored to the map, so if you need something anchored you need to use an annotation. Hope that helps.